# mvn versions:display-plugin-updates - structured output

Tags: maven

is there any way of making "mvn versions:display-plugin-updates" output dependencies in a structured format (e.g. CSV, XML or JSON) so that it can be easily parsed?

Comment: It's an open source project https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin and you can create an implementation and make a pull request of it.. ?

Comment: thanks - that would certainly be an option, however, maven output is pretty hard-wired, even the line width is hard-coded (https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/275)

Comment: a colleague of mine has created a bash script which takes the output; Either him or me will provide the script here

Answer (score 3):

So, without any warranties, here is a piece of bash script thanks to a colleague of mine that takes an output from display-plugin-updates|display-dependency-updates and converts to a comma-separated list; supports multi-line-outputs and works for us

```
#!/bin/bash

source_file=/opt/report.txt
target_file=/opt/comma_report.txt

#Clean source file from "[INFO]"
sed 's/\[INFO\] //g' $source_file > /tmp/clean_report.txt

#Join next line to the previous one if it starts with more than 3 spaces
sed -i -E ':a ; $!N ; s/\n^   / / ; ta ; P ; D' /tmp/clean_report.txt

#Clean file from more than 2 spaces
sed -i 's/  *//g' /tmp/clean_report.txt

#Grep for arrows, sort and send result to grepped_report.txt
grep "\->" /tmp/clean_report.txt | awk '!x[$0]++' > /tmp/grepped_report.txt

#Clean file from ".RELEASE"
sed -i 's/.RELEASE//g' /tmp/grepped_report.txt

#Replace arrows with commas
sed -i 's/->/,/g' /tmp/grepped_report.txt

#Replace more than 2 dots with comma and send the output to target file
sed -r -e 's/\.{3,}/,/g' /tmp/grepped_report.txt > $target_file

#Delete tmp files
rm /tmp/clean_report.txt
rm /tmp/grepped_report.txt

#The end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and nowadays there is an easy solution.

First of all you have to use `versions:dependency-updates-report` instead of `versions:display-dependency-updates`.

```bash
./mvnw versions:dependency-updates-report
```

By default it generates an HTML file at `target/site/dependency-updates-report.html`. Change the [configuration](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/dependency-updates-report-mojo.html#formats) in your `pom.xml` to get the result in XML format.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>xml</formats>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now run the goal again and you should see the XML file at `target/dependency-updates-report.xml`.

I'm using [dasel](https://github.com/TomWright/dasel) to work with this file in my CI/CD pipelines. The pipeline breaks a soon as I have an outdated dependency.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o pipefail

# run maven to generate dependency report
./mvnw versions:dependency-updates-report

# use default report location
REPORT="target/dependency-updates-report.xml"

# get the number of dependencies using the latest version
NEXT_VERSION_AVAILABLE=$(cat ${REPORT} | dasel --read xml ".DependencyUpdatesReport.summary.nextVersionAvailable")
NEXT_INCREMENTAL_AVAILABLE=$(cat ${REPORT} | dasel --read xml ".DependencyUpdatesReport.summary.nextIncremetalAvailable")
NEXT_MINOR_AVAILABLE=$(cat ${REPORT} | dasel --read xml ".DependencyUpdatesReport.summary.nextMinorAvailable")
NEXT_MAJOR_AVAILABLE=$(cat ${REPORT} | dasel --read xml ".DependencyUpdatesReport.summary.nextMajorAvailable")

# compare number of outdated dependencies with our threshold
if [ "${NEXT_VERSION_AVAILABLE}" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: ${NEXT_VERSION_AVAILABLE} next versions are available"
    exit 1
elif [ "${NEXT_INCREMENTAL_AVAILABLE}" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: ${NEXT_INCREMENTAL_AVAILABLE} next incremental versions are available"
    exit 1
elif [ "${NEXT_MINOR_AVAILABLE}" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: ${NEXT_MINOR_AVAILABLE} next minor versions are available"
    exit 1
elif [ "${NEXT_MAJOR_AVAILABLE}" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: ${NEXT_MAJOR_AVAILABLE} next major versions are available"
    exit 1
fi
```

I hope that helps you and anyone who might come here after some searching online. Let's make sure we're not using outdated dependencies in our Maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below command to list the dependencies of a project in CSV format against a pom file, you can tweak the command with `versions:display-plugin-updates` according to your need -

```
dependencyVersions=`mvn -U versions:display-dependency-updates -Dversions.outputLineWidth=120 -DprocessDependencyManagement=false -DprocessPluginDependenciesInPluginManagement=false|grep " -> "|awk '{print $2","$4","$6}'`;
while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done< <(printf '%s\n' "$dependencyVersions")
```

- `-U` = Force check for updates from remote
- `versions:display-dependency-updates` = List all dependency updates
- `-Dversions.outputLineWidth=120` = Required Versions plugin version > 2.10.0
- `-DprocessDependencyManagement=false` and `-DprocessPluginDependenciesInPluginManagement=false` = To exclude those from the list

The while part prints the output line by line